# Remove Tags menu item from Magento Admin

Tags: php, magento

Under the Catalogue option in the magento admin menu is an option called Tags. I would like to remove this option - is there an easy way to do it?

I have tried creating an adminhtml.xml file in /etc containing the following but it didn't work:

```
<?xml version="1.0" ?>
       <config>
            <menu>
                <tag>
                    <disabled>1</disabled>
                </tag>
            </menu>
       </config>
```

Thanks.

Comment: Do you mean Product Tags tab ?

Comment: In the Magento Admin, top menu, Catalogue->Tags.

Answer (score 1):

1) You can disable the Tag module output in the admin area.

See menu `admin > system > configuration > advanced > disable module output`.

2) To disable the whole module completely please open `app\etc\modules\Mage_All.xml` file,

find lines

```
<Mage_Tag>
    <active>true</active>
    <codePool>core</codePool>
    <depends>
        <Mage_Catalog/>
    </depends>
</Mage_Tag>
```

and replace `true` with `false` . Clear the cache.

Comment: I have disabled Mage_Tag in teh module output and it removes the tags functionality from the front end but the option still appears in the magento admin (Catalogue->Tags).

Comment: If you don't need the tag module, you can completely switch it off.

Answer (score 1):

Here are the steps you should follow:

1. `Dashboard > System > Config > Advanced > Mage_Tag > Disable > Save`
2. Clear cache

If you still see the option, try disabling caching in the Magento admin pages and then try again.

Comment: We tried this initially but it didn't work. Removed tags from front end but left the option in the admin area.